# Summation relating factorial and cosine

Tags: summation, factorial, trigonometric-series

How to simplify 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^{k}\left(k!\right)^{2}}\cos\left(kx\right)
\end{align*}

for $0\leq x <\pi$ ? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: If $x=\Re(x)$ than your sum converges to $$\frac{\sqrt{1+e^{-xi}}+\sqrt{1+e^{xi}}}{2\sqrt{2+e^{-xi}+e^{xi}}}$$

Comment: The result of @JanEerland can be simplified to $\cos(x/4)/\sqrt{2 \cos(x/2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you know that $$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^{k}\left(k!\right)^{2}}x^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}
$$ the problem can be solved in the following manner.

Consider $$I=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^{k}\left(k!\right)^{2}}\cos\left(kx\right)$$ $$J=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^{k}\left(k!\right)^{2}}\sin\left(kx\right)$$ $$I+iJ=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^{k}\left(k!\right)^{2}}e^{ikx}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{4^{k}\left(k!\right)^{2}}\left(e^{ix}\right)^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{i x}}}$$

I am sure that you can take it from here.